# 'Property does not exist' errors in terminal but not Chrome console - Nuxt/Prismic

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, prismic.io

I'm using Nuxt and Prismic to create a product catalogue website. I'm currently working on fetching navigation sections (product categories) from Prismic to display in a sidebar.

Everything seems to be working fine (content loads and displays as expected), however I am seeing the following errors in the terminal window from which I am running `npm run dev`:

> ERROR  ERROR in components/Sidebar.vue:29:14
> 14:35:49 TS2339: Property 'fetch' does not exist on type '{ data(): {
> heading: string; sections: never[]; }; created(): void; methods: {
> fetch(): Promise; }; }'.
> 27 |     },
> 28 |     created() {
> 29 |         this.fetch()
> |              ^^^^^
> 30 |     },
> 31 |     methods: {
> 32 |         async fetch() {
>
> ERROR in components/Sidebar.vue:35:20 TS2339: Property '$prismic' does
> not exist on type '{ fetch(): Promise; }'.
> 33 |         const that = this;
> 34 |         // TODO : Move Prismic call to actions.ts - this.$store.dispatch('fetchSections')
> 35 |         await this.$prismic.api
> |                    ^^^^^^^^
> 36 |         .getByUID('navigation', 'categories')
> 37 |         .then(function(document) {
> 38 |             console.log(document)
>
> ERROR in components/Sidebar.vue:37:24 TS7006: Parameter 'document'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.
> 35 |         await this.$prismic.api
> 36 |         .getByUID('navigation', 'categories')
> 37 |         .then(function(document) {
> |                        ^^^^^^^^
> 38 |             console.log(document)
> 39 |             that.heading = document.data.doc_name[0].text
> 40 |             that.sections = document.data.nav
>
> ERROR in components/Sidebar.vue:39:18 TS2339: Property 'heading' does
> not exist on type '{ fetch(): Promise; }'.
> 37 |         .then(function(document) {
> 38 |             console.log(document)
> 39 |             that.heading = document.data.doc_name[0].text
> |                  ^^^^^^^
> 40 |             that.sections = document.data.nav
> 41 |         })
> 42 |     }
>
> ERROR in components/Sidebar.vue:40:18 TS2339: Property 'sections' does
> not exist on type '{ fetch(): Promise; }'.
> 38 |             console.log(document)
> 39 |             that.heading = document.data.doc_name[0].text
> 40 |             that.sections = document.data.nav
> |                  ^^^^^^^^
> 41 |         })
> 42 |     }
> 43 |     }
>
> ERROR in components/SidebarSection.vue:43:26 TS2339: Property
> 'section' does not exist on type '{ name: string; props: { section: {
> type: ObjectConstructor; required: boolean; }; isCollapsed: { type:
> BooleanConstructor; }; }; mounted(): void; }'.
> 41 |     },
> 42 |     mounted() {
> 43 |         console.log(this.section.items[0].sub_nav_link_label[0].text)
> |                          ^^^^^^^
> 44 |     }
> 45 | }
> 46 |

This is despite the fact that I'm not seeing any errors in the Chrome console output.

Here is `export default` within `Sidebar.vue`:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            heading: "",
            sections: []
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.fetch()
    },
    methods: {
        async fetch() {
            const that = this;
            // TODO : Move Prismic call to actions.ts - this.$store.dispatch('fetchSections')
            await this.$prismic.api
            .getByUID('navigation', 'categories')
            .then(function(document) {
                console.log(document)
                that.heading = document.data.doc_name[0].text
                that.sections = document.data.nav
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The only potential issue I can think of is that I'm using the following declaration file to provide typescript type information about the Prismic API: https://github.com/prismicio/prismic-vue/issues/5#issuecomment-723652806

Perhaps there could be an issue in the way in which I am linking this? It's within a `types` folder and I reference it within:

```
"files": [
  "prismic.d.ts"
]
```

in tsconfig.json.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I just tried running `npm run dev` from within VSCode rather than a separate terminal window, and now I'm seeing errors throughout the project, whenever I try to use a Prismic type. This one is perhaps most telling:

`import { PrismicAPI } from '~/types/prismic'`

> Cannot find module '~/types/prismic' or its corresponding type
> declarations.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be with the way, `prismic.d.ts` is included in `tsconfig.json`. Can you try to use `include` option instead of `files` in `tsconfig.json`, and use the absolute path of `prismic.d.ts` there?
Like:

```
{
  "include": ["types/prismic.d.ts"]
}
```

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this in your code:

```
that.heading =document.data.doc_name[0].text
that.sections = document.data.nav
```

It's meant to be:

```
this.heading =document.data.doc_name[0].text
this.sections = document.data.nav
```

That way you can access it from the reactive data.